# google drive sdk multiple users

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to use the Google Drive SDK. For the most part, it works fine. However, if multiple users are logged in, it does not. The user is asked to select an account, but the account that is loaded is chosen seemingly at random.

Comment: When you say "the account that is loaded is chosen seemingly at random", do you mean in Javascript? Cause otherwise it works fine (for me) via web browser. What's the question? Can you provide some code here??

Comment: I'm guessing he is referring to this scenario. User is logged in to multiple Google accounts. When calling gapi.auth.authorize, user is presented an account picker, user selects an account, the auth token that is returned is for an account other than the one picked. I have seen the same thing.

Comment: yes, pinoyyid, that's exactly correct.

Comment: Are there any fixes for this? I am having the same issue.